# Can a windows hosted WCF service use HTTPS?

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a WCF service that is using webHttpBinding on an endpoint, and the WCF service is hosted as a windows service.  Is it possible to secure this at the transport level by using HTTPS or some other method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes - you can use HTTPS or even an SSH tunnel if you wanted to.

[Here is the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768.aspx) that explains how to configure WCF for HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks.  This is another link i found that might help for anyone else looking around:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733791.aspx#

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried to do this with a Windows Service, but here is how I have successfully secured a WCF service using IIS and shared certificates.  The biggest difference is that instead of being in the registry as a windows service it's a .svc file hosted up by ASP.net and your service implementation must have the AspNetCompatibilityEnabled attribute flagged to TRUE

- <s>[Server Config](http://pastie.org/406026)</s>
- <s>[Client Config](http://pastie.org/406035)</s>

see also:

- [stack overflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335719/how-can-i-configure-wcf-to-use-x509-certificates-over-the-internet)
- [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751427.aspx)
- <s>[wcf security patterns](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=How%20Tos)</s>