# Setting up web services with x509 and multiple clients and how to distinguish clients?

Tags: wcf, web-services, wcf-security, x509certificate, x509

Following these [two](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36683/9-simple-steps-to-enable-X-509-certificates-on-WCF) [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335719/how-can-i-configure-wcf-to-use-x509-certificates-over-the-internet), I was able to implement a simple web service with x509 certification, and an authenticated test client to consume the service.

Right now, it looks something like this:

```
 --------------
| ServiceA.svc | ------------> Test Client 1
|  -GetData()  |
 --------------
```

How can I extend what I have to accomplish something like this:

```
 --------------
| ServiceA.svc | ------------> Test Client 1
|  -GetData()  | ------------> Test Client 2
|  -SaveData() |
 --------------
| ServiceB.svc |-------------> Test Client 1
|  -GetData()  |
 --------------
| ServiceC.svc |-------------> Test Client 2
|  -SaveData() |
 --------------
```

I already have services set up, and Test Client 2 ready to go.

So here are some of my questions:

- Do I need to create a separate certificate for Test Client 2?
- How will the config files/end points/behaviors look like? I think Service B and C would be easy to setup as it is basically the same as what I have right now, but now that ServiceA will be consumed by both clients, I am a bit lost.
- If ServiceA is called how do I know which client is calling it? I potentially want to limit the methods they can call (ie. TC1 can only use GetData(), TC2 can only use SaveData()), and be able to log who is accessing the methods.

I can post what I have on the config files if needed, but it looks basically what the two aforementioned links have.

Comment: Exactly the question I was after.. +1

Comment: Can you please post what you ended up doing by answering your questions?

Comment: •Do I need to create a separate certificate for Test Client 2?
(Yes)
•How will the config files/end points/behaviors look like? I think Service B and C would be easy to setup as it is basically the same as what I have right now, but now that ServiceA will be consumed by both clients, I am a bit lost.
(multiple 'behavior' nodes in the config file)

Comment: •If ServiceA is called how do I know which client is calling it? I potentially want to limit the methods they can call (ie. TC1 can only use GetData(), TC2 can only use SaveData()), and be able to log who is accessing the methods.
(In code, use `ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, each client needs a separate certificate. Then from within the operation you can get its distinguished identity:

```
ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name
```

The best practice is to separate the authorization process like described here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc948343.aspx

Comment: Thanks! That was an informative article. Follow-up question(s): Would the primary identity name be the same as what I name my certificate with? In the first link of my original post, the client certificate is named 'WcfClient', am I validating the primary identity name with this exact string?

Comment: I believe the primary identity would be the subject name of the certificate, which is indeed WcfClient here. All the other parts of the certificate are not guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: Thanks again. I just tested it and it gave me something like "CN=WcfClient;FJFJD78FSDSOME0HASH0CODE0HERE" which I can definitely use.