# x509 certificate based authentication on Azure WCF service on webrole

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, x509certificate, access-control

I have a WCF service hosted on a `WebRole` in Azure. I would like to setup a federated ACS authentication based on `x509` certificate. I am following this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh289316.aspx) for guidance.
In the example cited, they are trying to instantiate a ServiceHost object in the console app and then dynamically apply the configurations. However, in my scenario, I am hosting the WCF over a webrole, so how do I retrofit the same configurations in web.config instead of programatically configuring it? This is because I wont be able to access the ServiceHost object at runtime when the WCF service is hosted on a IIS based webrole.

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335719/how-can-i-configure-wcf-to-use-x509-certificates-over-the-internet) solution not works for you? About hosting service in the web - just create .svc file and put next code inside:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Service="YourServiceName" Factory="YourHostFactoryName" %>
```

The other issue you can have is how to correctly install certificate in the web role.

Comment: This is pretty much what I have tried to do but I need the configurations specifically for Azure hosted WCF which as ACS federated authentication.